# Stream file upload to AWS S3 using go

Tags: file-upload, go, amazon-s3

I want to stream a multipart/form-data (large) file upload directly to AWS S3 with as little memory and file disk footprint as possible. How can I achieve this? Resources online only explain how to upload a file and store it locally on the server.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

you can do this using [minio-go](https://github.com/minio/minio-go) :

```
n, err := s3Client.PutObject("bucket-name", "objectName", object, size, "application/octet-stream")
```

PutObject() automatically does multipart upload internally. [Example](https://github.com/minio/minio-go/blob/master/examples/s3/putobject.go)

Comment: I think it's not the proper answer, cause here we can't have control on parts, while the AWS API gives us access to uploads each part separately and send initial/complete/abort upload commands.

Comment: The example linked here doesn't actually use `PubObject` to stream.

Answer (score 42):

You can use [upload manager](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-go/api/service/s3) to stream the file and upload it, you can read comments in [source code](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/blob/master/service/s3/s3manager/upload.go#L162) 
you can also configure params to set the [part size, concurrency & max upload parts](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-go/api/service/s3/s3manager/#Uploader), below is a sample code for reference.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "os"

    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/aws/credentials"

    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/aws"
    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/aws/session"
    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/service/s3/s3manager"
)

var filename = "file_name.zip"
var myBucket = "myBucket"
var myKey = "file_name.zip"
var accessKey = ""
var accessSecret = ""

func main() {
    var awsConfig *aws.Config
    if accessKey == "" || accessSecret == "" {
        //load default credentials
        awsConfig = &aws.Config{
            Region: aws.String("us-west-2"),
        }
    } else {
        awsConfig = &aws.Config{
            Region:      aws.String("us-west-2"),
            Credentials: credentials.NewStaticCredentials(accessKey, accessSecret, ""),
        }
    }

    // The session the S3 Uploader will use
    sess := session.Must(session.NewSession(awsConfig))

    // Create an uploader with the session and default options
    //uploader := s3manager.NewUploader(sess)

    // Create an uploader with the session and custom options
    uploader := s3manager.NewUploader(sess, func(u *s3manager.Uploader) {
        u.PartSize = 5 * 1024 * 1024 // The minimum/default allowed part size is 5MB
        u.Concurrency = 2            // default is 5
    })

    //open the file
    f, err := os.Open(filename)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("failed to open file %q, %v", filename, err)
        return
    }
    //defer f.Close()

    // Upload the file to S3.
    result, err := uploader.Upload(&s3manager.UploadInput{
        Bucket: aws.String(myBucket),
        Key:    aws.String(myKey),
        Body:   f,
    })

    //in case it fails to upload
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("failed to upload file, %v", err)
        return
    }
    fmt.Printf("file uploaded to, %s\n", result.Location)
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. If my file is below 5 MB it still will be streamed to S3? But as I understand anyway this file will appear on S3 only after been fully uploaded?

Comment: yes, it will be streamed in one part. correct, the file will appear once fully uploaded.

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to mount the S3 bucket with [goofys](https://github.com/kahing/goofys) and then stream your writes to the mountpoint. goofys does not buffer the content locally so it will work fine with large files.

Answer (score 1):

Was trying to do this with the aws-sdk v2 package so had to change the code of @maaz a bit. Am leaving it here for others -

```
type TokenMeta struct {
    AccessToken  string 
    SecretToken  string 
    SessionToken string 
    BucketName   string
}


// Create S3Client struct with the token meta and use it as a receiver for this method
func (s3Client S3Client) StreamUpload(fileToUpload string, fileKey string) error {
    accessKey := s3Client.TokenMeta.AccessToken
    secretKey := s3Client.TokenMeta.SecretToken

    awsConfig, err := config.LoadDefaultConfig(context.TODO(),
        config.WithCredentialsProvider(credentials.NewStaticCredentialsProvider(accessKey, secretKey, s3Client.TokenMeta.SessionToken)),
    )
    if err != nil {
        return fmt.Errorf("error creating aws config: %v", err)
    }

    client := s3.NewFromConfig(awsConfig)
    uploader := manager.NewUploader(client, func(u *manager.Uploader) {
        u.PartSize = 5 * 1024 * 1024
        u.BufferProvider = manager.NewBufferedReadSeekerWriteToPool(10 * 1024 * 1024)
    })

    f, err := os.Open(fileToUpload)
    if err != nil {
        return fmt.Errorf("failed to open fileToUpload %q, %v", fileToUpload, err)
    }
    defer func(f *os.File) {
        err := f.Close()
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Errorf("error closing fileToUpload: %v", err)
        }
    }(f)

    inputObj := &s3.PutObjectInput{
        Bucket: aws.String(s3Client.TokenMeta.BucketName),
        Key:    aws.String(fileKey),
        Body:   f,
    }
    uploadResult, err := uploader.Upload(context.TODO(), inputObj)
    if err != nil {
        return fmt.Errorf("failed to uploadResult fileToUpload, %v", err)
    }

    fmt.Printf("%s uploaded to, %s\n", fileToUpload, uploadResult.Location)
    return nil
}
```

Answer (score -2):

I didn't try it but  if i were you id try the multi part upload option .

you can read the doc [multipartupload](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/mpuoverview.html) .

[here](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/blob/0d69769150f236a0fee9a372c2faee638f57bba4/service/s3/examples_test.go)  is go example for multipart upload and multipart upload abort.

Comment: hm looks like I can only use ReaderSeeker for the body which I think implies that direct streaming isn't possible